# operator ++ applied two times, depending on arguments to #define function

Tags: c, macros, increment

On the snipet below, the operator ++ is called two times.

Why ??

```
#define CALL_WITH_MAX(a,b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))

int main()
{

    int a = 5, b =0;
    CALL_WITH_MAX(++a,b);
    // a was incremented by one two times !!!!

    CALL_WITH_MAX(++a,b+10);
    //a incremented as expected...

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Expand the macro, and you will see why.

Answer (score 4):

```
CALL_WITH_MAX(++a,b)
```

expands to

```
((++a) > (b) ? (++a) : (b))
   ^             ^           //A is incremented twice when ++a < b
```

---

`++a = 6` and `b = 0`
`6 > 0 == true`
`++a` is returned => `++a = 7`

In your second option

`++a = 6` and `b = 0 + 10 = 10`
 `6 > 10 == false`.
  This time just `b` is returned.

Answer (score 1):

Because argument is taken as is - without extracting variable names, etc. That's what it becomes:

```
((++a) > (b) ? (++a) : (b));
```

As incremented `a` is greater than `b`, the second part of ternary expression will be evaluated as well.

In the second case, however, the clause is falsy: 6 is less than 10. That's why third part of the ternary is evaluated instead, and `a` will be incremented just once.

Answer (score 1):

If the first argument is larger than the second, it is evaluated 2 times.

Therefore in the first case you have:

```
(++a) > (b) ? (++a) : (b)
```

and since `(++a) > (b)` you get `(++a)`, which increments `a` once more.

Answer (score 1):

If you expand the macro it will become like

```
((++a) > (b) ? (++a) : (b))
```

`6 > 0` then `a` is again incremented.

Answer (score 0):

The macro expands to:

```
((++a) > (b) ? (++a) : (b))
```

vs.

```
((++a) > (b+10) ? (++a) : (b+10))
```

in the former, ++a is evaluated twice

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in your code, you chose to name the macro's parameters `a` and `b`, which is also the name you used for your variables within your main function.

In my opinion, the problem you're having here is you probably think by naming them the same that they're linked somehow.. which is simply not true.

The parameters names in the macro don't tie them to variables of the same name in the program, they’re replaced by what you pass in. You might find this easier to see if we change the names a bit:

```
#define CALL_WITH_MAX(x,y) ((x) > (y) ? (x) : (y))
```

Then in your main program:

```
int a = 5, b =0;
CALL_WITH_MAX(++a,b);
```

Now you can see that `x` is replaced with `++a` and `y` will be replaced by `b`. So the logic of your macro becomes:

```
if  x  > y then return x   else return y
if ++a > b then return ++a else return b
if   6 > 0 then return 7   else return 0
```

So obviously 6 is greater than 0, so you increment again and return the value.

```
// a = 7; b = 0
CALL_WITH_MAX(++a,b+10);
```

So again, the same logic:

```
if  x  > y  then return x   else return y
if ++a > b  then return ++a else return b
if   8 > 10 then return 9   else return 10
```

In this case 8 is not greater than 10, so we don't increment to 9, we just return 10. Thus after the first call to your macro `a` was incremented twice and after the second call `a` was only incremented once; hope that made it clearer.

Comment: Yikes... apologies... I misread your statement... Deleting my comment.

Comment: @anishsane - NP, I'll reword a little to maybe make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers on this questions are correct. Here is a typical fix for the issue:

```
#define CALL_WITH_MAX(a,b) ({ typeof(a) _a=a; typeof(b) _b=b; ((_a) > (_b) ? (_a) : (_b)); })
```

Works with gcc.

Basically, it creates a copy of a & b, with same data types & operates on these copies.
The only time `a` gets incremented is at `_a=a;` statement in macro.

You can test the expansion with `-E` flag to `gcc`; like `gcc -E test_macro.c` ...

Answer (score 0):

The macro is not "compiled", it's completely different from writing a function you run during the execution of your application. Treat a macro as something that helps you write your code, not perform calculations.

Therefore

```
CALL_WITH_MAX(++a,b)
```

will generate

```
((++a) > (b) ? (++a) : (b));
```

which then is "read" by the compiler and compiled to actual code. This means that `a` will be incremented twice, because `b` is smaller than `a`, and therefore the `(++a)` is run. If b is larger, then the second `(++a)` is not executed and only `b` is returned.

This is why macros are also known as [**preprocessor** directives](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/), because they are used in the preprocessing phase of the build process. The values of the variables are not read or changed, the directive just reads the text you provide it with and generates code for you.

If you look at macros that already exist like `__LINE__`, it will return the line number for you in your code; however it will literally insert it as part of your code, it will not be a function that is run during the execution of your application. Similarly the macro `__TIME__` will not return the current time but the time of when the compilation process was started.

I hope this will help you to change your approach to macros and how they work.

Answer (score 0):

The prefixed increment operator has higher order of procedure so the value of the variable is increased by 1 before evaluation .

you call your function with arguments `(++a,b)`  so you need to replace all the variable with this passed value so the function can be expressed as

`CALL_WITH_MAX(a,b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))

CALL_WITH_MAX(++a,b); `

so if you replace all `a` by `++a` and `b` and `b` then your function can be expressed as

`((++a) > (b) ? (++a) : (b))`

the value of a is incremented by 1 before evaluation ..